# Returning a String Array

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ArrayHelpers{
    public static void main(String[] args){

      String arr[] = {"M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "X5M", "M750Li"};
      String stockElements[] = {"BMW M2 Coupé","BMW M3 Sedan", "BMW M4 Coupé", "BMW M5 Sedan","BMW M6 Gran Coupé", "BMW X5 M", "BMW X6 M", "M 750Li"};   
      int size = 7;
      printArrayQuantities(arr);
      System.out.println(getRandomElement(arr));
      System.out.println(getRandomArray(size, stockElements));
   }

   public static void printArrayQuantities(String[] arr){
      int num[] = {2, 1, 3, 3, 5, 1};

      for( int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
         System.out.println(arr[i] + " " + num[i]);

      }



   }


   public static String getRandomElement(String[] arr){
      int randomNum = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * 6);
      return arr[randomNum];


   }

   public static String[] getRandomArray(int size, String[] stockElements){
      String[] randArray = new String[size];
      for( int i = 0; i < size; i++){

         randArray[i] = getRandomElement(stockElements);

      }
      return randArray;
   }








}
```

So I'm trying to return an array that has been randomly inserted with elements from `stockElements` through `getRandomElement` method. When I'm trying to print that array from line 12 (`System.out.println(getRandomArray(size, stockElements));`) it produces `[Ljava.lang.String;@6d06d69c` as output. I'm aware of the `.toString()` method, but a requirement of my assignment is that I **do not use any built in array methods**. How exactly would I go about doing this?

Comment: You're trying to print the whole array, try iterating over the elements and print each one separately.

Comment: Are you trying to print the elements of the array?

Comment: @opensam At the core of it, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is just to iterate over it with **`for each loop`**.

```
String[] myArray = getRandomArray(size, stockElements); // this stores a reference of the returned array.
for(String str : myArray){
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

or with **`for loop`** if you prefer.

```
String[] myArray = getRandomArray(size, stockElements); // this stores a reference of the returned array.
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    System.out.println(myArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: The issue is that I need it to be returned rather than just printed.

Comment: it is returned. this stores a reference to the returned array -->String[] myArray = getRandomArray(size, stockElements)

Comment: Oh I see what you're trying to do now. Still learning arrays so it's a bit confusing

Comment: @JodhanveerGhangheri no problem. is this want you wanted to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Since your function is returning an array, when you try to print the array you should be iterating through each elements with a for/while loop and printing them individually. Since you're trying to print the *array variable* it instead prints java's *handle* for it. So try something like this

```
String[] randomArray = getRandomArray(size, stockElements);
for (String s : randomArray) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the array returned, just need to assign it:

```
String[] newArray = getRandomArray(size, stockElements);
```

But... if you want to just print it go with the below.

Using Java 8:

```
String.join(delimiter, newArray);
```

or (for older Java):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(String s : newArray) {
    builder.append(s);
    builder.append(delimeter);
}
return builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `System.out.println(getRandomArray(size, stockElements));` with 
   `String [] output = getRandomArray(size, stockElements);
          printArrayQuantities(output);`